# Django TimeZone issue with postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to save Date-Time in postgres table but It got changed after insertion.

My Django Model and Insertion Query:

```
class Notifications(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True, default='')
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,default=datetime.now)

    @classmethod
    def create_or_update(cls):
        try:

            entity = cls()

            entity.message = 'message'

            import dateutil

            entity.start_time = dateutil.parser.parse('04/18/2017 1:39 AM')

            entity.save()

            return 1

        except Exception as ex:
            return 0


    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'app_notifications'
        permissions = ()
```

SQL Output:

> start_time: 2017-04-17 18:39:00-07

Actual Input:

> 04/18/2017 1:39 AM

I have tried to convert the time but same result:

```
def to_aware_datetime(datetime_str):
    try:
        ret = parse_datetime(datetime_str)

        if not is_aware(ret):
            ret = make_aware(ret)

        return ret.astimezone(pytz.utc)

    except Exception as ex:
        return ''
```

Output:

> to_aware_datetime('2017-04-18 01:18') --> 2017-04-17 18:18:00-07

How can I resolve the issue? Thanks

Comment: It looks like the AM/PM needs to be after the time with no space https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html

Comment: @MHornbacher There is no issue with parsing. it saved the data into DB.

Comment: It seems to me that the issue you are having is that the wrong time is being entered into the database. From the code you posted it seems that that is a result of the parsing (2017-04-17 18:39:00-07 is the format used int the DBS and it translates to 04/17/2017 6:39 PM UTC

Comment: Parser returns: datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 18, 1, 39)

Comment: That is the current UTC time. In the docs for the parser you are using it will use UTC (or "safe") timezone if none specified. You can try changing the timezone in settings.py to the timezone you wish to use in production